# hibernate inheritance select from

Tags: sql, hibernate

I have question: Let's assume I have two classes User and Employee, Employee extends User, in User I have @Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED). Is it correct to get Employees in this way "FROM User p WHERE p.login = :login AND p.password = :password"; Login and password attributes are in User.

ERROR:
`org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: USER is not mapped [FROM USER p WHERE p.login = :login AND p.password = :password]`

Comment: What happens when you try it? Note that this is not a SQL query, but a HQL query.

Comment: I still get NullPointerException

Comment: Then why don't you ask why you're getting a NullPointerException, showing us your code and the full stack trace of the exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HQL uses class names and mapped attribute/properties names. Always. It doesn't use table and column names. Never. So, if your class is named `User`, as you initially said in the question and as it should be named to respect the Java naming convention, the query you asked for should work fine:

```
FROM User p WHERE p.login = :login AND p.password = :password
```

The exception says that the query, in fact, is

```
FROM USER p WHERE p.login = :login AND p.password = :password
```

which is invalid, as the exception says, because USER is not the name of a mapped entity class.

Also, note that the exception is not a NullPointerException, but a QuerySyntaxException.

Comment: I changed it and restarted server but eclipse cheated on me and haven't restarted server so i thought that it was different error, but now it works